# For simple things like setters, is it better to use an interface or abstract class?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, setter

I have several classes where I have public setter methods that I want to enforce.

I can either define the setter explicitly with an `abstract` class and then extend that class, *or* I can implement an `interface`. But with an `interface` I would have to write the setter method over and over again, which seems to violate the DRY principle.

```
public abstract class AbstractParent {
    int value;
    protected void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void setValue(int value);
}
```

When does it make sense to use which approach?

Comment: If you have to write the same thing over and over again it doesn't make sense to make it abstract. Define it in the superclass, and if it changes in a particular subclass, simply override it.

Comment: Doesn't that mean I *should* make it an abstract class then? Define the setter in the abstract class (using `protected`) and then override it if I want to? I'm not saying to make the setter method abstract in the abstract class -- that's basically the same as using an interface, which is the other part of my question to begin with.

Comment: I added code to clarify

Comment: How does the interface help you? You can have a default body in interface methods as of Java 8, but if you don't have that, you'd still have to define the method in every class. Your first example seems to be the proper one.

Answer (score 2):

The most abstracted ("best") way is to use *both*:

```
// The contract
public interface MyInterface {
    void setValue(int value);
}

// A convenient implementation from which to base a concrete implementation
public abstract class AbstractParent implements MyInterface {
    int value;
    void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You can see this pattern in action throughout the JDK, for example:

```
interface Map {...

abstract class AbstractMap implements Map {...

class HashMap extends AbstractMap {...
```

This pattern *allows* coders to provide their own classes that adhere to the contract, which can be particularly important when unit testing code that uses these objects, because it's much easier to mock an interface than a class, which might be final, have private constructors, or other inconvenient features.

Comment: What is the purpose of using both? And doesn't this require me to violate DRY principle in some way? Now if I change a method in the interface I have to change it in the abstract class, etc. But anyways, why both?

Comment: @ArukaJ Not at all. Where's the duplication? See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Changing interfaces doesn't happen very often, because that's changing the *contract*, or *API*. Changing *implementations* however *is* common.

Comment: Regarding Liskov: if T is the parent of S, then T can be replaced with S? What? How does that apply here?

Comment: But aren't the functions in the abstract class already part of a contract by default? Anything inheriting that class will require that function to be defined, either explicitly in the abstract class, or overridden and implemented in the child class.

Comment: @ArukaJ yes, but you don't impose a class hierarchy on all implementations. Java only allows single class inheritance. But interfaces let you use any class hierarchy that "looks like" the interface type. See edits to answer re testing (and same applies to developing prod code too)

Comment: I am sure you are right but I still don't understand (none of those sentences, to be honest, other than "Java only allows single class inheritance", which I do know). Can you show an example of when it's problematic without the extra interface vs. when it's a good idea?

Comment: @ArukaJ It's almost always a good idea. The reasons are beyond the capacity of this comment box. Read up on software design. Perhaps it's enough to say "if the collections library does it, it must be a good design principle"

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, it makes more sense to use an abstract class to define the common functionality of your setters, especially if all of the setters for the child class are the same.

With an abstract class, you could define the common setters once and be done with it. If needed you could then specify (with abstract functions) only the specific functions that need to exist and be unique per subclass.

With an interface, each method in it is essentially abstract so you would be forced to write each method in it over and over for each child class. Any future changes to the setters would need to be repeated for each child class. Copy paste errors or just forgetting one when updating could be disastrous.

If you're looking to enforce the template and not repeat yourself, an abstract class is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `Interface` instead of `abstract` class should be used if you want to  have a pure contract without implementation or your child classes must already extends another class and you are annoyed because a class cannot extends two classes.

If it is not the case, an abstract class should be enough.
Don't do complicate when you can do easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is the thumb rule is
1. Use Abstract Class when you want to move common implementation from client(sub) classes else do not use abstract as java provides only one class to extend.
2. Use interface class to enforce client class to implement the behavior so that you client class still has provision to extend the other classes if needed.

```
public interface SetterInterface {
    void setValue(int value);
}

// Here MyClass is can still extend any other class if needed, 
class MyClass implements SetterInterface {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use composition than inheritance.
Can you pull this value and setter out into another class and then have an instance of this class as member in the other classes.
It is a lot cleaner than mucking about with inheritance hierarchies